# Cannot set state of multiple checkboxes?

Tags: reactjs, checkbox, react-hooks

I am rendering multiple checkboxes:

```
className, content, visible, handleFeaturesChange}= props;
```

...

```
<FormCheck type="checkbox" label={"parking"} name={"parking"} onChange={handleFeaturesChange}></FormCheck>
<FormCheck type="checkbox" label={"Laundry"} name={"laundry"} onChange={handleFeaturesChange}></FormCheck>
```

from parent component:

```
function handleFeaturesChange(event) {
// event.preventDefault();
  const {name, checked} = event.target
  setFeatures({
    ...features,
    [name]: checked
  })
}
```

But this results in state being over-riden onChange so that only one checkbox is recorded as checked in any instance.

How do I get multiple checkboxes to work together?

Comment: For anyone googling this, my solution was to add individual useState hooks for each variable (parking, laundry, etc), and selecting which setState to use in handleFeaturesChange. Initializing all in one hook and referencing via 'checkedItem.parking', for example,  just did not work even with all below solutions.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're not binding the state value to each checkbox. It looks like this can be fixed by binding the values:

```
<FormCheck 
  type="checkbox" 
  label={"parking"} 
  name={"parking"} 
  onChange={handleFeaturesChange} 
  checked={features.parking}
/>
```

Note: This assumes the `FormCheck` component takes a `checked` prop. If not, you'll need to add that to `FormCheck`.

Answer (score 0):

you have store the checkBox values in a global variable then setState on that variable,otherwise you are just setting state for current checked box value

Note:this is not correct code,this is only for your understanding and I am assuming setFeatures as a function where You setState()

```js
let globalCheckBox=[]

<FormCheck 
  type="checkbox" 
  label={"parking"} 
  name={"parking"} 
  onChange={handleFeaturesChange} 
  checked={features.parking}
/>

function handleFeaturesChange(event) {
  const {name, checked} = event.target

globalCheckBox.push({name, checked})

  setFeatures({
...features,
   globalCheckBox

  })
}
```

`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the state hook, useState.

```
const [checkedItems, setCheckedItems] = React.useState([false, false])
```

Then:

```
<Checkbox
    isChecked={checkedItems.parking}
    onChange={e => setCheckedItems([e.target.checked, checkedItems.parking])}
/>
```

https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html